# Как вывести viewbox на середину SVG?

Tags: svg

Указываю viewbox чтобы подсмотреть возможные дефекты на "неидеальном" стыке круга, но никак не могу сделать так, чтобы этот участок был на SVG крупным и по середине. Ведь я указываю viewbox с учетом одинаковых отступов от целевой точки как вправо-лево, так и верх-низ.

А в реальности изображение получаю прижатым к какому-либо краю. Все статьи почитал здесь по поводу viewport - viewbox, только про позиционирование вроде ничего и не нашел.

Нужно во всей красе увидеть участок "60 109.99999 60.00002 110.00001".

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="60 109.99999 60.00002 110.00001">
    <path d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
</svg>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> но никак не могу сделать так, чтобы этот участок был на SVG крупным и
> по середине.

**Шаг 1.** Узнаем **физические размеры** фигуры SVG

Если точнее  сказать, то нужно узнать ширину и высоту ограничивающего фигуру svg прямоугольника и его координаты x,y от верхнего левого угла холста SVG.

*Используем js метод getBBox()*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="60 109.99999 60.00002 110.00001">
    <path id="path" d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
</svg>  
<script>
let bb = path.getBBox()
console.log(bb)
</script>
```

**Шаг 2.**  Подставляем полученные цифры из консоли в параметры viewBox и для того, чтобы изображение не занимало всё окно браузера, добавляем `viewport` в заголовок SVG   `width="99.99"` `height="99.99"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="99.99" height="99.99" viewbox="10 10 99.99 99.99" style="border:1px solid red">
    <path id="path" d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
</svg>  
<script>
let bb = path.getBBox()
console.log(bb)
</script>
```

Фигура SVG заняла симметрично всё пространство viewport (пользовательской области просмотра) и естественно стала расположена ровно по середине.

**Шаг 3.** Если есть необходимость увеличить изображение, допустим в 10 раз, то увеличиваем `viewport` в 10 раз `width="999.9"` `height="999.9"` при тех же значениях параметров `viewBox`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="999.9" height="999.9" viewbox="10 10 99.99 99.99" style="border:1px solid red">
    <path id="path" d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black"  fill="none"/> 
</svg>  
<script>
let bb = path.getBBox()
console.log(bb)
</script>
```

**Обратите внимание на вывод в консоли**, что физические размеры фигуры, остались прежними, изменился только размер отрисованной фигуры в пользовательском окне просмотра.

**Шаг 4.** При необходимости, чтобы рассмотреть полностью нижнюю границу фигуры можно поднять изображение с помощью изменения 2-го параметра viewBox

было:  viewbox="10 10 99.99 99.99"
стало: viewbox="10 70 99.99 99.99"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="999.9" height="999.9" viewbox="10 70 99.99 99.99" style="border:1px solid red">
    <path id="path" d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black"  fill="none"/> 
</svg>
```

Для правой границы viewbox=`"70 10 99.99 99.99"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="999.9" height="999.9" viewbox="70 10 99.99 99.99" style="border:1px solid red">
    <path id="path" d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110 z"
       stroke="black"  fill="none"/> 
</svg>
```

Разрыв линии при разнице координат начала и конца намного меньше `1px` увидеть не возможно. Так как минимальная единица в SVG 1px. Всё что меньше воспроизводится при рендеринге с эффектом Сгла́живание (англ. anti-aliasing) То есть вместо чётких границ разрыва, будут серые прямоугольники.

Comment: Дошло))) Я же во viewbox вторыми параметрами указывал вторые координаты, а надо было абсолютную ширину и высоту, то есть 2 и 1)) А то все никак не врубался как это получается так... Спасибо, как всегда классный ответ. Немного не понятно почему меньше 1px не увижу, я же без единиц измерения прописывал. И почему в width и height без единиц измерения можно прописать, а можно и 900px, например, прописать... Немного запутано как-то все))

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4xjbro9u/ - засек разрыв если убрать "z", только на stroke, на заливке ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была здесь: `viewbox="60 109.99999 60.00002 110.00001"`. Передаю вторыми параметрами `60.00002` и `110.00001`, полагая, что это `x2` и `y2` соответственно, а должны быть указаны `"width"` и `"height"`:

```
viewbox="60 109.99999 0.00002 0.00002"
```

Убираю `"z"` из пути, чтобы дуга не смыкалась и пробую повторить уже с правильным `viewbox`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="60 109.99999 0.00002 0.00002">
    <path d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110"
       stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
</svg>
```

Видимо, масштаб маленький, но после недолгих манипуляций с шириной охвата viewbox, получаю таки видимый разрыв в кривой:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="59.988 109.496 0.024 0.008">
<path d="M60 110 A 50 50 0 1 1 60.00001 110"
   stroke="black" fill="rgb(180,180,255)"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: В XHTML так бы и было, а здесь работает и `viewbox` и `viewBox` совершенно одинаково))

Comment: давно видать спецификация поменялась - я не знал об этом

Comment: @MaximLensky, все правильно. Если это отдельный файл SVG, то viewBox надо указывать, потому как в XML регистр имеет значение, но если мы встраиваем SVG в HTML, то регистр значения не имеет, как и для написания тегов и атрибутов. Ваше замечание считаю уместным, лучше приучать себя писать правильно всегда (как предполагалось в свое время при переходе на XHTML, который так и не состоялся))).